# Using Ctrl+B in less within tmux

Tags: tmux

I use the `Ctrl+B` command prefix in `tmux`, however this clashes with `Ctrl+B` in `less`, which is used for scrolling up a file.

How can I get this to work? Do I have to set a different command prefix in `tmux`? I really don't want to have to learn new key bindings if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Obviously you can't have two keys that do the same thing when both programs are listening. Tmux is going to get it first. You didn't specify which set of key bindings you don't want to re-learn, but you have to do something different because the same key is used for both apps.

If you only use it occationally in `less` you can just pass the real thing on by hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (that's Ctrl-B twice) in `tmux` to pass on a single Ctrl-B to the app in the current pane.

If you want to change the `tmux` binding to be something else (say like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> like `screen`) you can add this to your `~/.tmux.conf file:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
```

If you want to use something else for `less`, the <kbd>G</kbd> key is usually bound to go to the top of the file already, so no changes necessary. If that change doesn't suit you, you can rebind keys using [`lesskey`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lesskey).

Comment: If I change the tmux binding to `Ctrl+A`, that will clash with beginning-of-command. I also have 'Ctrl+B+B' bound to previously selected window.

Comment: @Caleb: In my `tmux` (Ubuntu 11.04 with the default config), "Ctrl+B B" does nothing (nor is it documented in the man page); one has to use "Ctrl+B Ctrl+B" to send a Ctrl+B to the application.  (By contrast, `screen` defaults to using "Ctrl+A A" to send a "Ctrl+A" to the application.)  Excellent answer, anyway.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri: That's a nomenclature problem. I didn't leave a space in between `B` keys that would indicate letting up on the control. Normally with styled keys like that you would put a space or comma between keys if the control key was going to be released, but it's not a well defined standard. Some people don't even use the same `+` syntax...

Comment: @dogbane: If you re-bound a double CTRL-B to something other than the default, that's your fault and you will either have to remap that, map the pass through version of CTRL-B to something else, or use a different key for less.

Comment: @dogbane I use `Ctrl+\ `, but this is obviously a matter of personal preference. You won't like my choice if you don't have a way of typing `Ctrl+\ ` on your keyboard without finger contortions.

Comment: Commenting on this old thread because I came looking for the answer and couldn't find it. To replicate the actual behavior of Screen, I found the solution to be a variation of what @diabloneo suggested:
`set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix`

Similarly to what happens in Screen. by pressing Ctrl-a-a will send Ctrl-a to the program in the shell.

Answer (score 19):

In [tmux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) with the default configuration, pressing Ctrl+B *twice* sends *one* Ctrl+B to the application.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the tmux command `send-prefix`. It will send your tmux key-binding prefix to the current window

For example, in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key v send-prefix
```

Then, pressing `Ctrl-a` + `v` will send `Ctrl-a` to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using <kbd>Page Up</kbd> ;)